# What is Skype - Business Version?

Tags: skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Skype Business version](https://superuser.com/questions/21858/using-skype-business-version)

The page on Skype is so full of marketing jargon and such and I have trouble distinguishing what really is the difference between the regular Skype client and the Business version. Could someone help to enlighten me?

What are the main differences between the personal and business versions of Skype?

Comment: @slhck, Yeah I've already read that one, but couldn't really find what I was asking about there. Seemed to be mostly about msi stuff? I'm looking for a simple list with features that are different.

Comment: Ok then :) So basically, what else apart from being able to have one SkypeOut account and a centralized contact list?

Comment: @slhck Well, those should be included in the list probably, but yes :)

Answer (score 0):

With the Skype Business edition there seems to be a focus on PBX integration and centralized administration for an office manager, but the full list of features is still unclear (and there doesn't appear to be anything helpful on Skype's web site):

Difference between Skype for Home and for Business?
  http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090625105045AAmVe6X

I also noticed that the required questions for downloading Skype were not required with the business version at first, but eventually this changed and now both versions require the user provide personal information prior to downloading.